ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
I use python 3.9.18 as an virtual environment, I've been trying to set up my local environment for airflow. When I run airflow standalone command, I constantly get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'. I was using python 3.8.4 and uninstalled it along with the vurtula env, then installed 3.9.18 along with a new venv, but still the same

Why don't you install sqlite3?

I installed through sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev, it didn't work with python 3.9.18 or 3.8.4 but with python 3.8.18 i didn't get this modeulenotfound error. Airflow runs locally fine now. Thanks.
